# Binary Tree graphical representation troubles

Tags: java, swing, jtree

So I have a user-defined binary tree class that I'd like to represent graphically. JTree seems to be the best option here. My class has a reference to its current position, to allow the user easier traversals and abstract the inner Node class. When the next is called, it traverses and returns the value of the Node.

For the most part, I've been able to get these trees to work together, but I've run into an issue when the user adds a node. I have it set up so they can add either a left choice or a right choice - this matters with the data I'm keeping, so it needs to be this way - and I'm totally stuck on how to do this. The way I've implemented it currently irrevocably desyncs the trees, to the point of needing to quit and reinitialise to regain sync.

Here are the methods I'm having problems with:

Some info:

-Here, dTree is an object of my tree class, and gTree is a JTree object (data tree, graphics tree)

-The method getShortName(String) returns the normalised name used to represent the current node in the JTree, which is extrapolated from the dTree object.

```
//Adds a new right node to the currently selected node.
public void addNextR()
{
    if(!dTree.hasNextR())
    {
        dTree.addNextChoiceR("Empty Node");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = 
        ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)gTree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent());
        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(getShortName(dTree.getCurrent())));
        expandTree();
    }
}

//Adds a new left node to the currently selected node.
public void addNextL()
{
    if(!dTree.hasNextL())
    {
        dTree.addNextChoiceL("Empty Node");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = 
        ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)gTree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent());
        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(getShortName(dTree.getCurrent())));
        expandTree();
    }
}
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone could help me with this problem, and I hope I've followed the correct procedure and given enough info. Sorry about the wall of text, I'm just trying to make sure I get my problem across. Thanks for at least reading this far, though!

Comment: I see that providing a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be complicated here, but ...: Only adding the new child node to the parent node will not properly update the TreeModel (and thus the Tree) itself - that's what you probably mean with "desyncing". You'll have to call http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#insertNodeInto%28javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode,%20javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode,%20int%29 . Also see how this is used in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic

Comment: Yeah, thats why I've been holding off asking this for a while, trying to figure it out myself, but no luck so far. What I mean by desyncing is that my place marker for the data tree becomes out of step with the place marker for the graphical tree. A revalidation is called elsewhere, and doesn't appear to change the outcome. What I'm getting from this is that I'm on the right track, though? With adding the child nodes, I mean.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "revalidation", and **I** can not judge which track is the right one for you ;-) But running the "DynamicTreeDemo" from the tutorial site and comparing it to your node insertion (particularly regarding `DefaultMutableTreeModel#insertNodeInto` can hardly be the *wrong* track, at least.

Comment: Just read the link properly, my bad, I assumed you were saying I'd need to call revalidate(). I'll have another read of this and see if there was anything else I missed, or if it just clicks over in my brain.

Answer (score 0):

I used three classes for ease of understanding and making changes easily.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class TreeNode
{
TreeNode left,right;
int data;
TreeNode()
{
    data=0;
    left=right=null;
}
TreeNode(int n)
{
    data=n;
    left=right=null;
}
void disp()
{
    System.out.println(data+" ");
}
void setLeft(TreeNode n)
{
    left=n;
}
void setRight(TreeNode n)
{
    right=n;
}
TreeNode getLeft()
{
    return left;
}
TreeNode getRight()
{
    return right;
}
void setData(int d)
{
    data=d;
}
int getData()
{
    return data;
}
}


class BinaryTree
{
TreeNode root;
BinaryTree()
{
    root=null;
}
void insert(int data)
{
    root=insert(root, data);
}  
TreeNode insert(TreeNode node, int data)
{
    if(node==null)
    {
        node=new TreeNode(data);
    }
    else
    {
        if(data<=node.data)
        {
            node.left=insert(node.left, data);
        }
        else
        {
            node.right=insert(node.right, data);
        }
    }
    return(node);
}
void inorder()
{
    inorder(root);
    System.out.println();
}
void inorder(TreeNode r)
{
    if(r!=null)
    {
        inorder(r.getLeft());
        System.out.print(r.getData()+" ");
        inorder(r.getRight());
    }
}
void preorder()
{
    preorder(root);
    System.out.println();
}
void preorder(TreeNode r)
{
    if(r!=null)
    {
        System.out.print(r.getData()+" ");
        preorder(r.getLeft());
        preorder(r.getRight());
    }
}
void postorder()
{
    postorder(root);
    System.out.println();
}
void postorder(TreeNode r)
{
    if(r!=null)
    {            
        postorder(r.getLeft());
        postorder(r.getRight());
        System.out.print(r.getData()+" ");
    }
  }
  }


  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  class btTraversal
{
BinaryTree bt;
void main() throws IOException
{
    bt=new BinaryTree();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int val;
    char ch=' ';
    String clearbuffer;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        val=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        bt.insert(val);
        System.out.print("Do you wish to enter more values (Y/N).....");
        ch=(char)br.read();
        clearbuffer=br.readLine();
    }while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
    System.out.println("Postorder traversal of given tree is: ");
    bt.postorder();
    System.out.println("Preorder traversal of given tree is: ");
    bt.preorder();
    System.out.println("Inorder traversal of given tree is: ");
    bt.inorder();
}
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my problem. I have no issue with the actual binary tree class, my issue is with the JTree representation and using the GUI to add and remove nodes to both data and graphical trees synchronously.

Comment: No worries. Thanks, though. In either case this is quite a concise answer, just the wrong question! Haha

Comment: Sure, why the hell not. It's probably helpful to somebody, right?